# How to create a Google Spreadsheet pivot table from multiple sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, pivot

Is it possible to create a pivot table that consolidates data from multiple sheets?

Answer (score 2):

no, it's not. first, you will need to gather your data from all sheets with a query and then create your pivot table:

```
=QUERY({Sheet1!A:Z; Sheet2!A:Z; Shet3!A:Z}, "select * where Col1 is not null", 0)
```